# 301 Redirect, need to drop file name

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, 301-redirect

I have many redirects working but I have one that needs to be redirected and drop the file name.

```
redirect 301 /path/to/file/default.aspx http://www.domain.com/newpath/to/page/
```

When I implement this it tries to redirect but it does not drop the default.aspx from the URL.

**Edit**
Rewrite Rules:

```
 ## path relative to web root
 RewriteBase /

 ## workaround for HTTP authorization
 ## in CGI environment
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

 ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

 ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

 ## rewrite everything else to index.php
 RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

**EDIT 2**
The only other directives would be in the vhost config and there is not alot there:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.100.216:80>
ServerName web01.domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/htdocs
SetEnvIf X_FORWARDED_PROTO https HTTPS=on
RewriteEngine on
<Directory /var/www/domain.com>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That directive shouldn't result in the behaviour you see, are there any other `Redirect` directives which are relevant?

Comment: Please edit your question when adding additional details instead of using comments.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for `Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) says that

> Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.

so your `Redirect` line is appending the unwanted filename.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/to/file/default.aspx$
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/newpath/to/page/
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this did not fix the redirect. It still takes me to the site root.